# Query with table as a parameter

Tags: android, android-room

I'm trying to create an Abstract DAO instead of reimplementing the same query multiple times. I tried

> ```
> @Query("SELECT * FROM :table WHERE id = :id")
> public abstract LiveData<T> load(String table, int id);
> ```

I have an issue saying that

> Error:(23, 33) error: no viable alternative at input 'SELECT * FROM :table'

Is that even possible to achieve what I want to achieve ?

Thank you !

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you cannot use `:table` there. The `:foo` placeholders only go where `?` placeholders can go, which is mostly (if not exclusively) in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: that means that it's impossible to achieve what I want to achieve: an Abstract DAO.

Comment: AFAIK, you are correct. See if somebody [has filed a feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:197448) for this, and if not, file one!

Comment: And here I filled a request : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64268642

Thanks for the suggestion ;)